# Collision and direction in Unity C#....?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm using this code to move to right direction:

```
transform.Translate(1,0,0);
```

Then I'm using this to move to opposite direction, I need to change x axis positive/negative.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){

}
```

Help me to make it happen....
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. But if you want to move object to the left use `transform.Translate(-1,0,0);`

Comment: yes it is but i still cant make it happen with collision

Answer (score 0):

**This Is for newbie like me, it's work for me!**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CollisionAndtheMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    public bool  toRight;`enter code here`
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        toRight = true;


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update (){
        if (toRight) {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.right*Time.deltaTime*speed, 0);
        }

        if (!toRight) {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.left*Time.deltaTime*speed, 0);
        }

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Crate" && toRight) {
            toRight = false;
        } else {
            toRight = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your code, you didn't format it correctly for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform.Right` for the purpose and for opposite direction 
`-transform.Right` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To go the opposite direction, just make the number negative.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
  transform.Translate(-1,0,0);
}
```